# Bundler can't see gems in a dockerized environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, rubygems, bundler

I've been trying to dockerize a rails application for azure web containers. All seems to go well in the creation process, bundler runs and apparently installs the gems. However, when I ssh into it and go into the app directory to run the rails console i get the error message that rails isn't installed. I've tried running it both with bundle exec and without, and I've even tried to run the compiled console manually, but that just throws the error that rake isn't installed. I've been racking my brain with this for days now and I've tried countless configurations of the Dockerfile but nothing seems to work. Here's my current Dockerfile for reference.

```
FROM ruby:2.6.3

ENV SSH_PASSWD "root:Docker!"

# Update and install packages
RUN apt-get update \
       && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs \
       && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends openssh-server \
       && echo "$SSH_PASSWD" | chpasswd  \
       && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_11.x | bash - \
       && apt-get install -y nodejs \
       && npm install -g yarn

# Bundler config
ENV GEM_HOME=/bundle
ENV BUNDLE_PATH $GEM_HOME
ENV BUNDLE_APP_CONFIG=$BUNDLE_PATH \
BUNDLE_BIN=$BUNDLE_PATH/bin
ENV PATH /app/bin:$BUNDLE_BIN:$PATH

# Upgrade rubygems
RUN gem update --system

# Set working directory
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy Files
COPY Gemfile* package.json yarn.lock ./
COPY sshd_config /etc/ssh/
COPY init.sh /usr/local/bin/

# Set permissions for init script
RUN chmod u+x /usr/local/bin/init.sh

# Install bundler and gems
RUN bundle install
RUN yarn install --check-files

#Copy Code
COPY . ./
EXPOSE 3000 2222

ENTRYPOINT [ "init.sh" ]
```

Comment: Have you installed Postgres on Azure? I'm not to familiar with Azure but on Heroku there are custom commands for accessing things like the console. For example 'heroku run rails c'. Should it be just `rails c` on Azure I assume you're running it as a virtual machine? Have you tried running the command `rails -v?

Comment: No, but as far as I know bundler doesn't interact with the db at any point. This seems to me to be a problem with bundler itself, or its configuration. I'm running rails in a container, and I'm directly ssh-ing into it so the commands should be the same as on any normal system as I'm not executing them through azure. Rails -v just says that rails isn't installed even though I ran bundle install in the Dockerfile.

Comment: Right but you said "...go into the app directory to run the rails console"

Comment: I mean in the same way you would on your local machine. I ssh into the container,  cd to the app directory and try to run the console, or any rake task, and bundler starts saying that the gems aren't installed.

Comment: And if you run `rails -v`?

Comment: It says `bundler: command not found: rails  
Install missing gem executables with bundle install`, even though they were installed during docker build.

Comment: ...and what happens if you run `bundle install`?

Comment: If I bundle install it manually it works, but being that this is supposed to be a part of the CI/CD pipeline for this app, it's infeasible to do this manually every time a new release comes out, which is why I was hoping to figure this out.

Comment: How are you running the container?  What's in the `init.sh` file?  Why have you set up ssh access with a known, fixed password in clear text in your source?

Answer (score 0):

For this one, try running 'bundle config' as your environment may already be configured to have bundler use the default files.  Once bundler sets a config in your environment, all successive bundle runs will use that config.  Here's a sample of part of our **app.sh** that runs as the entrypoint/command.  This script removes the 'production' flags and installs dev dependencies if it's a dev build just before running the puma server.

`#!/usr/bin/env bash
if [[ "$RAILS_ENV" == "development" ]] || [[ "$RAILS_ENV" == "test" ]]; then
  echo "--> Installing development and test bundles"
  bundle config --delete without
  bundle install --with development,test
else
  echo "--> Installing production bundles"
  bundle install
fi`

In our case, we needed to delete the without clause as that was preventing installed gems from running during bundle install.